# Create variable inside template partials on handlebars

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, partials

Is there a way to define/create variable object inside a template and pass it to partial helper?
This is what I am trying to achieve.

```
    {{#defineVariable myData='{"images": ['..src1', '..src2']}' }}

    {{> somePartial myData}}
```

So that "somePartial" partial will have the data define above.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data to partials through hash parameters:

```
{{> myPartial param1=value1 paramN=valueN }}
```

Also you can pass a custom context to the partial:

```
{{> myPartial myOtherContext }}
```

In your particular case since you want to send a JSON string as context, you need a custom block helper to do that:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("parseJSON", function(string, data, options) {
    string = string.replace(/\{\{([\w]+)\}\}/g, function(str, group) {
        return data[group] || "";
    });

    return options.fn(JSON.parse(string));
});
```

And use it like this:

```
{{#parseJSON '{"images": ["{{src1}}", "{{src2}}"]}' this}}
     {{> somePartial}}
{{/parseJSON}}
```

Where `this` is the context that has `{{src1}}` and `{{src2}}` to be replaced.

**Here's a full example passing a JSON string as context.**

```js
//Compile main template
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#test-template").html());

//Register 'foo' partial
Handlebars.registerPartial("foo", $("#foo-partial").html());

Handlebars.registerHelper("parseJSON", function(string, data, options) {
  string = string.replace(/\{\{([\w]+)\}\}/g, function(str, group) {
    return data[group] || "";
  });

  return options.fn(JSON.parse(string));
});

//Your data
var data = [{
  src1: "http://i.imgur.com/9YimTCP.jpg",
  src2: "http://i.imgur.com/DadhsWa.jpg"
}, {
  src1: "http://i.imgur.com/DadhsWa.jpg",
  src2: 'http://i.imgur.com/9YimTCP.jpg'
}];


document.body.innerHTML = template(data);
```

```css
img { max-width: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<!-- template.html -->
<script id="test-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each .}}
    {{#parseJSON '{"images": ["{{src1}}", "{{src2}}"]}' this}}
       {{> foo }}
    {{/parseJSON}}
    <hr />
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="foo-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="foo">
     {{#each images}}
       <img src="{{this}}" />
     {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

**Example using hash parameters:**

```js
//Compile main template
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#test-template").html());

//Register 'foo' partial
Handlebars.registerPartial("foo", $("#foo-partial").html());

//Your data
var data = {
  "test": [{
    param: "Hi",
    partialParameter: 'Bar'
  }, {
    param: "Bye",
    partialParameter: 'Foo'
  }]
};


document.body.innerHTML = template(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="test-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each test}}
    <!-- Pass parameters to partial -->
    {{> foo custom='hardcoded' other=partialParameter}}
    <hr />
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="foo-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="foo">
    <div><strong>param:</strong>{{param}}</div>
    <div><strong>other:</strong>{{other}}</div>
    <div><strong>custom:</strong> {{custom}}</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

More info about partials [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html)